# Width/height scaling for image rotation with non-square pixels

Tags: python, image, user-interface, kivy

I am developing a GUI in Python using the Kivy framework. My GUI contains a windrose where an arrow (contained in a png image) rotates around a circle to indicate the current wind direction. The windrose is circular, however because the screen I am using has non-square pixels, the actual size of the windrose is 134 pixels wide by 145.940594 pixels high. The factor that needs to be applied in the vertical to account for the non-square pixels is 220/202 = 1.089108.

[image: WindRosePanel with arrow at 0 degrees]

Here is the snippet of code I have to rotate the arrow contained in the png file (which has dimensions 134 pixels by 134 pixels):

```
<WindSpeedPanel>:        # This WindSpeedPanel has dimensions of 262 pixels wide by 220 pixels high
    AnchorLayout:
        pos_hint: {'x': 65/262, 'y': 26/202}
        size_hint: (134/262, 134/202) 
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        Image:
            source: 'icons/windRose/arrow.png'
            size_hint: (1, 1)
            keep_ratio: 0
            allow_stretch: 1
            canvas.before:
                PushMatrix
                Rotate:
                    angle: -app.windDir
                    axis: 0, 0, 1
                    origin: self.parent.center
            canvas.after:
                PopMatrix
```

The issue I am facing is when the image is rotated (for example by 90 degrees), it becomes elliptical because of the width/height scaling required to account for the non-square pixels:

[image: 90 degree rotation with no scaling]

I can solve the two trivial cases where the rotation is

1. 0 degrees or 180 degrees (no scaling is required)
2. 90 degrees or 270 degrees (width is multiplied by 220/202, height is multiplied by 1/(220/202) - i.e. the dimensions are simply swapped)

[image: 90/270 degree rotation with scaling]

At the moment, however I can't solve the required scaling for all intermediate angles. I have tried various equations with sines/cosines to calculate the necessary width/height scale factors, but nothing seems to work. I always end up with the rotated png image being squashed/stretched into an ellipse. For example at 45 degrees with no scaling applied I see:

[image]

Does anyone have any insight on how I should be calculating the necessary width/height scale factors to ensure the png image remains circular irrespective of the rotation angle?

Answer (score 0):

I have hunch that the solution is to scale the width by `(220/202)*abs(sin(angle))` and the height by `(202/220)*abs(sin(angle))`.

angle is a variable that holds the angle (0 to 360 degress),

sin() is for sinusoid and abs() is for absolute value.

**Edit:**

Maybe a more accurate solution would be to treat the circle (windrose) as an ellipse.

So each point (x,y) on the circle is actually (assuming the circle is centered at point (0,0)):

```
x = 134 * cos(angle)

y = 145.940594 * sin(angle)
```

Comment: I hadn't thought about treating the circle as an ellipse. Let me give this a go and see what I get.

Comment: Haven't had much luck using the ellipse equations unfortunately. I tried defining the width and height as `width  = sqrt((134*cos(angle))^2 + (145.940594*sin(angle))^2)` and
`height = sqrt((134*cos(angle+90))^2 + (145.940594*sin(angle+90))^2)` (i.e. the length of the vector pointing in the direction of rotation (width) and rotation+90 degrees (height)), but it still gives an ellipse at 45 degrees. It works perfectly for 90 degrees.

Comment: I don't know how your code draws the windrose, but the arrow of the windrose will follow the (x, y) path that I described in my answer. Hope it helps.